# Построение теоретической и эмпирической функции распределения случайной величины (например, Пуассона) в python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Построение теоретической и эмпирической функции распределения случайной величины (например, Пуассона) в python.
Пусть у меня есть некая выборка np.array[5,4,5,2,4]. Как построить эмпирическую функцию распределения?

Comment: уточните суть вопроса, пожалуйста.

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2):

Эмпирическая функция распределения строится исходя из ряда распределения значений ряда, в народе часто путаемого с гистограммой. Тем не менее, ряд распределений строиться, например, функцией `numpy.histogram()`. Гистограммы - `hist()` в Matplotlib и Pandas,  `displot()` в seaborn.

C другой стороны оценка эмпирической функции распределения может быть сделана методом оценки плотности ядра (Kernel Density Estimation, KDE), и реализована функциями `plot.kde()` библиотеки Pandas, `gaussian_kde()` в SciPy (`scipy.stats`),  функциями KDEUnivariate и KDEMultivariate в `statsmodels.api` и `KernelDensity()` в Scikit-learn.

Понятно, что по пяти значениям никакую эмпирическую функцию распределения не построишь.

Значения теоретической функции распределения с заданными параметрами получаются в `scipy.stats` c помощью методов `pdf` 
(для плотности непрерывных - или `pmf` для дискретных распределений) и `cdf` (для интегральной функции) соответствующих объектов, в том числе norm - для нормального распределения или `poisson` - для распределения Пуассона.
Например `st.norm.pdf()` или `st.poisson.pmf()`.